# Linq Remove items from one list which is in another

Tags: c#, linq, compare

```
var returnUser = mailList.Where(A => !suppressUsers.Any(C => A.Email.Equals(C.Email)))
                                                   .ToList<User>();
```

From the above code what i want to do is to remove the users from the mail list who are in the suppressUsers list. is this code is correct? because for large no of data sets i am not getting the correct answer

Comment: try Trim() and ToLower()  while checking for equality. e.g  var returnUser = mailList.Where(A => !suppressUsers.Any(C => A.Email.Trim().ToLower().Equals(C.Email.Trim().ToLower())))
                                                   .ToList<User>();

Comment: This question is missing all kinds of information. What type of LINQ/Database? What is "not correct"?

Answer (score 0):

Thi should work for you :

```
var suppressusersarray = suppressUsers.select(x=>x.email).toArray();
var returnUser = mailList.Where(x=>     suppressuserarray.Contains(x.email)).ToList();
var result = mailist.except(returnuser);
```

Comment: The logic of this answer is acceptable due to the Example. But the question is about removing the items which can be done by Remove(). The question and the provided code for the question is misleading.